# Squeak Smalltalk- How to make to "Transcript show" print more things?

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

I am using Smalltalk to type in Transcript window a 1-9 multiplication table .

**Here is my code:**

```
1 to: 9 do: [:i|
    1 to: i do: [:j|
        Transcript show: j.
        Transcript show: ' * '.
        Transcript show: i.
        Transcript show: ' = '.
        Transcript show: j * i.
        Transcript show: '  '.
        ].
    Transcript show: ' '; cr.
    ].
```

As can be seen, the above code, although  working fine, looks far from beautiful and concise.

I had hoped to write something like :

```
Transcript show: j '*' i '=' j * i.
```

Unfortunately, they are wrong. I remember C has   a very nice way to handle that issue of mine.

Like, `printf("%d * %d = %d ", j, i, j * i);`

Is there a more elegant way to make Smalltalk codes elegant in this situation ?

---

Peter solves this problem. Thanks.

**More to ask:**

How to display "Escape character" in Smalltalk.

I know in C, `printf("%d * %d = %d\n", j, i, j * i);` seems fine.

But in Smalltalk, `Transcript show: ('{1} * {2} = {3}cr.' format: {i. j. i * j}).` is not OKAY.

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### String expansion

> Like, printf("%d * %d = %d ", j, i, j * i);

There are some options for formatting, but nothing comparable to printf (afaik)

```
'<1p> * <2p> = <3p>' expandMacrosWith: 2 with: 3 with: 2 * 3.
"same as the following:"
'<1p> * <2p> = <3p>' expandMacrosWithArguments: {2. 3. 2 * 3}.

'{1} * {2} = {3}' format: {2. 3. 2 * 3}.
```

So your code could be rewritten as the following

```
1 to: 9 do: [ :i |
    1 to: i do: [ :j |
        Transcript
            show: ('{1} * {2} = {3}' format: {j. i. j * i});
            show: ' '
    ].
    Transcript show: ' '; cr.
].
```

### Update re: escape characters

There are no escape characters in Strings with the only exception being single quote ('), which you "escape" by doubling it (`'It''s doubled!'`)

To write new line, or tabulator, you can

1. type it into the string

   `a := 'two
       lines'.` *(note that StackOverflow replaced the tab with spaces :/)*
2. Join strings

   `b := 'two', String cr, String tab, 'lines'.`
3. Tell write stream to add it

   `c := String streamContents: [ :stream | stream << 'two'; cr; tab; << 'lines' ].`
4. use expandMacros

   `d := 'two<n><t>lines' expandMacros.`

`a = b = c = d`

Comment: Thanks. That solves my problem. Forgot to ask.  How to display "Escape character" in Smalltalk. I know in C, printf("%d * %d = %d\n", j, i, j * i); seems fine. But in Smalltalk, Transcript show: ('{1} * {2} = {3}cr.' format: {i. j. i * j}).    is not OKAY. How can I solve that?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest two changes:

1. Have the code work with a generic `Stream` and use it with the `Transcript`

   ```
   dumpTableOn: aStream
      <your code here>
   ```

   And then evaluate

   ```
   self dumpTableOn: Transcript
   ```
2. Split your code in two methods

   ```
   dumpTableOn: aStream
     1 to: 9 do: [:i | 
       1 to: i do: [:j |
           self dump: i times: j on: aStream.
           aStream space].
       aStream cr]


   dump: i times: j on: aStream
     aStream
       nextPutAll: j asString;
       nextPutAll: ' * ';
       nextPutAll: i asString;
       nextPutAll: ' = ';
       nextPutAll: (j * i) asString
   ```

---

Here is a less verbose version of the method above

```
    dump: i times: j on: aStream
      aStream
        print: j;
        print: ' * ';
        print: i;
        print: ' = ';
        print: j * i
```

Note that `#print:` doesn't require us to convert the argument to a `String` first.

Note also that the cascade doesn't create intermediate `Strings`, while the expression

```
j asString, '*', i asString, '=', (j*i) asString
```

creates 4 intermediate strings (one for every `#,`). Not a big deal, except that we wouldn't be taking full advantage of the `Stream` protocol, whose whole point is to free the client from the need of concatenating things on its side.

Comment: Note also that this suggests an important change: from a "loose" script in a workspace, to methods in a class. That's a relevant step in Smalltalk, because creating a class to attack a problem is the first step in the exploration of a domain and capture of knowledge

Answer (score 2):

If you'd prefer to use something similar to `printf`, Squeak has the expandMacrosWith: family of methods (browse class String).

Your example could be written as:

```
1 to: 9 do: [:i|
    1 to: i do: [:j|
        Transcript show: ('<1p> * <2p> = <3p>   ' expandMacrosWith: j with: i with: j*i)
        ].
    Transcript show: ' '; cr.
    ].
```

The receiver of `expandMacros...` contains placeholders between angled brackets. I can't find the relevant documentation in Squeak, the following is taken from the comment to the equivalent implementation in Dolphin Smalltalk:

```
Expand the receiver with replacable arguments.
e.g.
    'Hello <D><N><1P> <D>' expandMacrosWithArguments: #('World' 1).
    'Hello <2?Good:Bad> <1S>' expandMacrosWithArguments: #('World' false)

<nD> expands the nth parameter using it's #displayString
<nP> expands the nth parameter using it's #printString
<nS> expands the nth parameter treating it as a <String>
<N> expands as a newline combination
<T> expands as a TAB
<n?xxxx:yyyy> if the nth parameter is true expands to 'xxxx' else 'expands to yyyy'
```